# Set up the triple integral to evaluate the volume V of the solid bounded by $z=x^2+3y^2$ and $y^2 + z =4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Set up the  triple integral to evaluate the volume V of the solid
>   bounded by $z=x^2+3y^2$ and $y^2 + z =4$

$$y^2 + z =4 \Rightarrow z =4 -y^2$$ putting this in the paraboloid :

$$z=x^2+3y^2 \Rightarrow 4-y^2 = x^2 +3y^2 \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 = 1$$

Now this is independent of $z$ so it is the required projection of the intersection of the two curves onto the $xy $ plane.

Thus we get the following integral:

$$V = 4\int_{0}^{1/2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}} \int_{x^2+3y^2}^{4-y^2} \; dz \; dy \; dx$$

Is this set up correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You may also say that
$$V = \iint_{\frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 \leq  1} \left((4-y^2)-(x^2+3y^2)\right) dx dy= 8\iint_{X^2 + y^2 \leq  1} (1-(X^2+y^2)) dX dy$$
where $x=2X$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: actually I've solved it using the cylindrical coordinates and got $4 \pi$ as answer. I just wanted to know if the integral I set up was alright

Comment: Yes the your set up AND the final result are correct.